# Removing Cookie value from browser

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cookies

I know that this has been asked many times, and ive tried using the accepted answers. But sadly none of that seems to work for me in my browser(Mozilla v18.0.2).

I am using backbone for my website and im using cookies to handle user login sessions.

The following are the unsuccessful ones :

Code 1

```
var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // now
cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 ); // one second before now.
// empty cookie's value and set the expiry date to a time in the past.
document.cookie = "uid=;expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
document.cookie = "userName=;expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
```

Code 2

```
var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){
            uid = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            return uid;
        }
 };
```

Any working solution for removing browser cookies??

Thanks

Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple answer

You can't.

### Long answer

You can overwrite the cookie and give it an expiration time in the past.

Browsers will discard it at some point after its expiration. Until then you need to check yourself, if it has been “deleted”, e. g. with a special value or by comparing the expiration date with the current time.

Comment: I tried giving this expiration date.. But still i get the cookie value in browser. Setting the expiration date doesnt seem to work for me atleast with the above two sets..:(

Comment: Edited to include an answer to your comment.